# Django atomic transactions not actually atomic?

Tags: django, django-models

I was recently in an interview for a fairly upper-level django job and they stated that atomic transactions aren't truly atomic. In all my years using django ive never heard this. can anyone explain?

Comment: What did they mean not truly atomic, what symptoms did they experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interviewers were likely unaware that changes were made in Django 1.6+ to resolve issues related to transaction management, including a new `atomic` method, where previously one would use `commit_on_success`.

## References

Django 1.6 changelog:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/1.6/#transaction-management-apis

Django 1.6 transaction documentation (with 1.5 transaction deprecation notices): https://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.6.x/topics/db/transactions.html